# Rank-one modification of a Laplacian as the Laplacian of a larger, weighted graph

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

The Laplacian $L$ is usually defined for simple graphs, that is, graphs with no self-loops or multiple edges. Consider however the $n\times n$ matrix $M=L+P$, where $P$ has null entries except for one diagonal element $p_{jj}=1$.

Assuming that the spectrum of $L$ is known, what can we say about the spectrum of $M$? More generally, are there interesting properties that 'carry over' from one matrix to the other?

**Edit 1.** This is apparently called a *rank-one modification*, as Igor Rivin wrote below. I'm basically interested in a generalized version of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712449/rank-one-modification-of-graph-laplacian).

Answer (score 0):

You are making a rank one update of the matrix $L.$ You can read about the eigenvectors in [this Wikipedia article][1] while the eigenvalues are discussed in Gene Golub's paper:

*Golub, Gene H.*, [**Some modified matrix eigenvalue problems**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/1015032), SIAM Rev. 15, 318-334 (1973). [ZBL0254.65027](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0254.65027).

The link to the PDF is actually in the above-mentioned Wikipedia article.
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunch%E2%80%93Nielsen%E2%80%93Sorensen_formula

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have just realized that I was wrong about the interpretation of $L'$, as adding a self-loop should not change the Laplacian of a graph. I will look into your linked articles, but I think that this stuff is a bit too general for what I have.

Comment: I have heavily edited the question to account for this mistake. As far I see, $L'$ cannot be interpreted as the Laplacian of a different graph.

Comment: @There'sStrangeStuffOutHere You are correct, though since I have no idea what your goal was, it was hard to tell if you were not doing what you wanted to do.

Comment: I have edited the question again. Please feel free to take a look, if you'd like to update your answer as well.